# In which order does docker image prune -a removes images

Tags: docker

Let's say I have 2 tags for the same image. Container is running with one of the image tags. When I do docker image prune -a docker removes the tag with which the collector is running. Is there a particular order in which the image is untagged?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `docker image prune -a` command, Docker removes unused images from your local system. including dangling and unreferenced images in the cleanup process. The order in which Docker removes images is as follows:

Dangling Images: Docker first removes any dangling images. Dangling images are those that have no associated containers and are not tagged. These images are typically created during the build process when you build a new image on top of an existing one without removing the previous one.

Unreferenced Images: After removing the dangling images, Docker proceeds to remove unreferenced images. Unreferenced images are images that are not associated with any running containers or other images that are currently being used.

---

When you have multiple tags for the same Docker image, and a container is running using one of those tags, the behavior of `docker image prune -a` can result in the untagging of an image. However, the order in which the image is untagged is not explicitly defined or guaranteed.